# Correct parent for modal dialog in Swing

Tags: java, macos, swing, dialog, modal-dialog

I have a bug with modal dialogs I'm running into with Java 8u151/8u152 that wasn't an issue in 8u112, and I'm not sure if I'm doing something inherently wrong, or if this is a JRE bug. This only affects Mac OS as far as I can tell (I'm running OS 10.12.6), so although my question isn't Mac-specific, you won't be able to observe this bug if you're not a Mac user.

I have a modal dialog created with the main JFrame as its parent. I then create a new modal dialog that I create from dialog #1. Is it wrong to set dialog #2's parent to the main JFrame as well? Or must it be dialog #2?

Asked another way: If both dialogs share the same parent (the main JFrame), but dialog #2 was created last, is it reasonable to expect that dialog #2 should be on top, or is the behaviour undefined?

With 8u112, dialog #2 was focused and on top. With 8u151, dialog #2 is focused but behind. If I click on either dialog, dialog #2 grabs focus and seems to behave appropriately for the most part. However, sometimes dialog #2 will remain on top of other applications (I believe this happens if I click on the main window, then back on the modal dialog... this part is definitely a bug).

Note: for Java 8u121 through (I think) 8u144, there were additional problems with modal dialogs that were supposed to have been fixed in 8u152 (I logged a bug report and checked an early access build several months ago, and things really were fixed back then).

Some sample code to illustrate what I'm doing:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main extends JFrame {
    MyPanel panel;

    public Main() {
        setTitle("This is a frame");
        setSize(300, 200);
        panel = new MyPanel(this);
        add(panel);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            Main frame = new Main();
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    private static class MyPanel extends JPanel {

        int dialogCounter = 1;
        final JFrame theParent;

        public MyPanel(JFrame parent) {
            super();
            theParent = parent;
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
            JButton button = new JButton("Press the button");
            button.addActionListener(e -> showDialog(theParent));

            add(button);
        }

        private void showDialog(Frame parent) {
            JDialog dialog = new JDialog(parent, "This is dialog " + dialogCounter, true);
            setupDialog(dialog);
        }

        private void setupDialog(JDialog dialog) {
            JPanel dialogPanel = new JPanel();
            dialogPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
            dialogPanel.add(new JLabel("Current dialog count: " + dialogCounter++));
            JButton button = new JButton("Open a new modal dialog");
            button.addActionListener(e -> showDialog(theParent));
            dialogPanel.add(button);
            dialog.add(dialogPanel);
            dialog.pack();
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If dialog 2 is been created from dialog 1 I would automatically assume that dialog 1 is the parent of dialog 2

Comment: It can be a little convoluted, but you can get the window ancestor of a component using SwingUtilities, you’ll then need to instanceof to determine if it’s a frame or dialog, but at least you don’t need to pass the frame reference about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug introduced in 8u151. It has already been fixed and should be backported to the next OpenJDK 8 update release. 
Below is a workaround you could use:

```
    dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
            dialog.removeWindowListener(this);
            dialog.toFront();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is there a bug ID for this from Oracle? We've been waiting for the Mac OS dialog bug introduced in 8u121 to be fixed for months now, it would be nice to know when we'll be able to update our Java version. It looks like it's still there in 8u162 (early access) as well as 9.0.1.

Comment: For anyone who's interested, I logged a bug report, so it now has bug ID JDK-8190522.